# TreeMap with custom comparator doesn't remove entries

Tags: java, treemap

So I have a `TreeMap` with a simple custom comparator which sorts the map based on its values.

```
    Map<Integer, Double> unsortedMap = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
    unsortedMap.put(..,..)
    ...
    ...

    Map<Integer, Double> map = new TreeMap<Integer, Double>(new SortValues(unsortedMap));

    public class SortValues implements Comparator<Integer> {
        Map<Integer, Double> map;

        SortValues(Map<Integer, Double> map) {
            this.map = map;
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(Integer one, Integer two) {
            if(map.get(one) >= map.get(two)) {
                return 1;
            } else
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
```

I print out the map and it looks fine. But when I do `map.remove(key)` it doesn't remove it cause I still see it there when I print it. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `compare` method is flawed, because it can't return `0`.  If the two objects are `equal`, then it needs to return `0`, not `1`.

Change your `compare` method to return `0` if the two `Integer`s are equal.

This will allow the `TreeMap` to find the `Integer`, which relies on `compare` returning `0` to determine equality.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of the `compare` method violates the contract. It is supposed to return `0` if two objects are equal. That's why it doesn't work.